# How to add widetext or one column text to the AAAI supplementary section header?

Tags: pdftex, sections-paragraphs

For `aaai18.sty` how to add a Supplementary materials section header as a one column?

[edited] Here is a sample. What I want is to make the Supplementary section a go across the top of the doc and then continue in two column. Moreover, I'd like to get any new figures or tables in the supplement to be show with the prefix 'S'.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\title{
My Good Title}
\author{John Doe\\
Technologies Institute \\
Some University \\
Springfield, PA 12345\\
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[3]
%\bibliographystyle{aaai.bst}
%\bibliography{hrg}

\include{supplement}

\end{document}
```

Where supplement looks like so:

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}
% \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[S#1]}
\renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{S#1}
\renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{\textit{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%% Prefix a "S" to all equations, figures, tables and reset the counter

\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Supplemental Materials: A far more interesting title like\\
Latent-Variable Probabilistic Widgets}
\end{center}

\section{Tree Explosions, it's real}
More formally, given a graph $H = (V,E)$, a \emph{tree decomposition} is a tree whose nodes, called \emph{bags}, are labeled with subsets of $V$, in such a way that the following properties are satisfied:
\begin{itemize}
\item For each node $v \in V$, there is a bag $\eta$ that contains $v$.
\item For each edge $(u,v) \in E$, there is a bag $\eta$ that contains $u$ and $v$.
\item If bags $\eta$ and $\eta^\prime$ contain $v$, then all the bags on the path from $\eta$ to $\eta^\prime$ also contain $v$.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: please provide small complete document which show your problem. now your question is not very clear.

Comment: Hope to make my question more clear with this sample code. when I use `onecolumn`/`twocolumn` the output doesn't look right. Using `widetext` causes other problems.  Using `onecolumngrid` doesn't work with document class `article`, thus I would love to know some other suggestions.

Comment: Where does `aaai18.sty` comes from? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: 2018 conf [AAAI Author Kit](https://aaai.org/Conferences/AAAI/2018/aaai18call.php).  Download the author kit's zip file and you end up with this file: `AuthorKit18/LaTeX/aaai18.sty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with your given code and your comment

> Prior to the Supplementary material, the doc is two column. I need a
>   newpage (or pagebreak) and then the new title accross the top with two
>   column body for the rest of it.

I think you want something like the following:

- With command `\onecolumn` you can change from two columns to onecolumn including a page break.
- With package `multicol` you can start a two column part with environment `\begin{multicols}{2}`

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{multicol} % <===============================================

\title{
My Good Title}
\author{John Doe\\
Technologies Institute \\
Some University \\
Springfield, PA 12345\\
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Methods}
\lipsum[3]
%\bibliographystyle{aaai.bst}
%\bibliography{hrg}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}
% \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[S#1]}
\renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{S#1}
\renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{\textit{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%% Prefix a "S" to all equations, figures, tables and reset the counter

\onecolumn % <==========================================================
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Supplemental Materials: A far more interesting title like\\
Latent-Variable Probabilistic Widgets}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2} % <================================================
\section{Tree Explosions, it's real}
More formally, given a graph $H = (V,E)$, a \emph{tree decomposition} is a tree whose nodes, called \emph{bags}, are labeled with subsets of $V$, in such a way that the following properties are satisfied:
\begin{itemize}
\item For each node $v \in V$, there is a bag $\eta$ that contains $v$.
\item For each edge $(u,v) \in E$, there is a bag $\eta$ that contains $u$ and $v$.
\item If bags $\eta$ and $\eta^\prime$ contain $v$, then all the bags on the path from $\eta$ to $\eta^\prime$ also contain $v$.
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols} % <=====================================================
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 0):

this is only extended comment ...

i'm still not sure, what you like to obtain. is maybe this?

[image]

if this is case, than you need in preamble load `multicol` package and write your supplement as:

```
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Supplemental Materials: A far more interesting title like\\
Latent-Variable Probabilistic Widgets}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Tree Explosions, it's real}
More formally, given a graph $H = (V,E)$, a \emph{tree decomposition} is a tree whose nodes,

 called \emph{bags}, are labeled with subsets of $V$, in such a way that the following properties are satisfied:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item For each node $v \in V$, there is a bag $\eta$ that contains $v$.
    \item For each edge $(u,v) \in E$, there is a bag $\eta$ that contains $u$ and $v$.
    \item If bags $\eta$ and $\eta^\prime$ contain $v$, then all the bags on the path from $\eta$ to $\eta^\prime$ also contain $v$.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
```

btw, supplement material usual belong to `appendix`.

**edit:** from comment follows, that given *mwe* is misleading, so i propose useless solution. it seems that all document is two column and supplement material, also in two column, should start on new page ... this can be simple achieve by adding `\clearpage` before `\include{supplement}` or in beginning of supplement file.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{aaai18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\title{
My Good Title}
\author{John Doe\\
Technologies Institute \\
Some University \\
Springfield, PA 12345\\
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[3]
%\bibliographystyle{aaai.bst}
%\bibliography{hrg}

\clearpage% or \cleardoublepage  if you like to start on odd page of two side document
\include{supplement}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No. This doesn't quite work. Prior to the Supplementary material, the doc is two column. I need a newpage (or pagebreak) and then the new title accross the top with two column body for the rest of it.

Comment: you should clarify in your question and indicate in given *mwe*. solution than is more than simple add `clearpage` before  `supplemenentary`.

Comment: Adding [this](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15770) does exactly what I want:

Comment: More complete: Thanks for `clearpage`. Adding [this](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15770) does exactly what I want: in the preamble add `\usepackage{cuted}
`. In the supplement  wrap the title like this:`\begin{strip}\centering Supplement Title \end{strip}`

Comment: but you in the first comment claim different: start supplement on new page. and in edited answer this is accomplished.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Your solution does not force the Supplement title to run accross the page (like the original title). Plus with `{multicols}{2}` your suggestion forces the supplement text to two colums in one, which is not what I want. The suggestion I posted keeps the original article as a standard two column article, and begins the Supplementary Work correctly on the next page after the bibliography with the supplement title accros the page followed by standard `twocolumn` for the rest of supplelment text.